# What is the best way to create CI/CD for AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, aws-api-gateway

We need to create CI/CD for API's in AWS API gateway which will be integrating with microservices running in EKS.

I have seen some blogs using cloudformation templates for creating end to end for serverless application.In our case we need to do only for API's and writing cloudformation for all the API's I think will be difficult as API complexity increases(VPC links ,transformation and other) . Please suggest me if this best way to do or is there other way .

Also can we use the API documentation using API export option(openAPI+API Gateway integration) from the AWS API gateway console to do CD for other regions in different AWS account ?

Can you please suggest me the best way to achieve.

Comment: Are you asking about something like the API Gateway poroduct as opposed to the more generic term of API Gateway? If so, I'm not sure why you'd use that with EKS (maybe you want some of the rate limiting from API Gateway?) as opposed to using a Kubernetes ingress controller.

As a note - complexity increasing is exactly where you *want* to use infrastructure as code to ensure that it's maintained properly. AWS CloudFormation or Terraform are really your two best options, though AWS also has a new method (AWS CDK) using more imperative programming that I haven't dabbled in yet.

Comment: @Patrick thanks for the reply ,I'm taking about the AWS API gateway which is managed service provided by AWS.If we want to use cloud formation for API creation then we need to mention each and every step for creating API like create rest API ,create resource ,create method,create schema and so on. is that right way ?

Comment: It's possible, yes, but it'll cost a lot of money to do so. You can see roughly what your architecture will look like in this AWS blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/api-gateway-as-an-ingress-controller-for-eks/

@kakollu - I'm not sure what benefit you're looking to get from AWS API Gateway as opposed to using an ALB Ingress controller in Kubernetes (ALB is still going to be fully managed by AWS, essentially) then routing based on Layer 7 path into your pods. That keeps everything with your yaml for kubectl, too.